# Need to control GPU-Fan speed (workaround for broken Hardware)

Tags: nvidia, overheating, fan, fancontrol

I'm kind of a Windows refugee, one of the last thing that is stopping me to run Ubuntu (16.4 Studio) on my PC is a workaround for my broken Nvidia Geforce GTX 760.

If i don't run a 3rd party tool to control the speed of my GPU-Fan the Fan will come to a full stop, when the GPU is under havy load.(resulting in emergency shutdown of the GPU)
On Windows I currently use MSI-Afterbruner to control my Fan speed.
(Which was very easy to setup with an adjustable(drag & drop) graph.)

My question now is there any tool, which is able to control the speed of the GPU-Fan depending on heat available on Ubuntu? (don't want to run the Fan at high speed, when the GPU is almost in Idle mode)

Thanks for your help.

Phil

Comment: The GPU should automatically regulate it's fan speed on its own, regardless of the driver. (At least, my GTX650 does)

Comment: Did you actually install the proprietary driver?

Comment: Yes, the latest drivers are installed(wen't through a clean reinstall of driver & OS), as i mentioned in my question, my graphic card suffers from a Hardware defect which causes a malfunction in it's fan speed control, that's why i need to run a 3rd party tool to take care of it.(Took several hours with NVIDIA support, to figure this out)